# Execute command constructed from property with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, properties

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$ export test1="a bc"
$ export test2="test3=${test1}def"
$ echo $test2
test3=a bcdef
$ export ${test2}
$ echo $test3
a
$ export test2="test3=\"${test1}def\""
$ echo $test2
test3="a bcdef"
$ export ${test2}
-bash: export: `bcdef"': not a valid identifier
```

In this example I'm trying to construct a command, using a property that has spaces. If I don't add escaped quotes to the property then obviously it ignores everything after the first space character. If I do escape the quotes then it fails to execute.

How can I configure this so that the final output of:

```
export ${test2}
```

Gives me

```
echo ${test3}
```

Equal to

```
a bcdef
```

Comment: I suspect you'll want to read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21) sooner than later.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to quote the parameter expansion of `test2` in the `export` command:

```
export test1="a bc"
export test2="test3=${test1}def"
export "$test2"
echo $test3
# output: a bcdef
```

Comment: "You are mistaken, ..." Yes, I see that you're right. Deleting my answer, as O.P. didn't bother to complain that it didn't work. But I'd still argue that most variable usage should be surrounded in dbl-quotes, in your case,  `echo "$test3"` . Good luck to all.